# Riddle with routing in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, routes

I made simply router with htaccess and PHP. But this way made impossible to set additional GET parametr in url.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
[...]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
[...]
```

index.php

```
[...]
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
$router = new Router($url);
[...]
```

and then i'm running dispatcher. For example url www.site.com/user/regierter runs `class UserController -> registerAction()`.But what if i want add another get request like:
**www.site.com/user/regierter?layout=red**.

How make it possible to dispatch url part but accept another get requests?

Comment: You are looking for the QSA flag for Rewrite Rules I assume: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html When will people finally start reading the documentation of the tools they use? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach to rewrite isn't favorable for this use case.

It's easier to simply use the internal redirect to get the request from your webserver to PHP and let PHP deal with the request parameters.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [PT]
```

This makes Apache httpd redirect *any* request that isn't a file or directory that exists in the document root, to `index.php` internally. Meaning, the redirect is completely transparent to the end-user. They see `www.example.com/foo` while your webserver sees `/index.php` and PHP just sees `/foo`. This makes it possible to handle the routing internally regardless of the query string parameters.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$router = new Router($url);
```

Any parameters in the query string still get parsed in `$_GET` appropriatly. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the original request URI passed to PHP by your webserver such that `www.example.com/foo/bar/?quix=1&quack=2` gets read by PHP as `/foo/bar/?quix=1&quack=2` and `$_GET['quix'] == 1` and `$_GET['quack'] == 2`.

So the original query string (i.e. the HTTP request line) remains untouched as far as PHP can tell. The only change made here is in how your web server determines whether to let PHP handle a request or to serve it up directly from the document root.

Now your router can extract all the information it needs from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` directly, with something like [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse-url), for example.

So if the request was made to **www.site.com/user/register?layout=red** `var_dump(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))` would give you something like this.

```
array(2) {
  ["path"]=>
  string(14) "/user/register"
  ["query"]=>
  string(10) "layout=red"
}
```

And `$_GET['layout']` will still give you `"red"`.

Comment: "your webserver sees `/index.php/foo`" - The "webserver sees" `/index.php` - there is no `/foo` appended to the end. (The `PT` flag would only be required in a server context, if at all.)

Comment: Yes, I'm explaining how the webserver is going to see the request *after* the rewrite rule. This is why I state internal redirect, and not external redirect.

Comment: Yes, it's just that the webserver sees `/index.php`, not `/index.php/foo`, as you've stated in your answer - maybe that's just a typo? (It would only become `/index.php/foo` if you explicitly appended the URL-path as _additional path information_ on to the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution.)

Comment: @w3dk Ahh! Indeed. Copy/pasta failure there. Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed now :)

Answer (score 2):

The `RewriteRule` flag [`PT|passthrough`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt) is only needed, if your target (index.php) is an Alias or similar

> That is to say, the use of the [PT] flag causes the result of the RewriteRule to be passed back through URL mapping, so that location-based mappings, such as Alias, Redirect, or ScriptAlias, for example, might have a chance to take effect.

So in your case this doesn't help, the use of flag [`L|last`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) is enough.

---

As @arkascha already mentioned, to keep the other get parameters, you must use the [`QSA|qsappend`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

This means your rule will become

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will give you both `$_GET['url']` *and* `$_GET['layout']` in your PHP script.

Comment: Good answer Olaf +1

Comment: The `PT` flag is _implied_ anyway in a per-directory context.